Solution of the (Paraxial) Helmholtz equation and angular spectrum representation of optical fields
In my lecture today, we were discussing the Helmholtz equation and it's approximation to the paraxial Helmholtz equation.
For the Helmholtz equation the solutions to it are of several kind:
1 - The wave function solution can be expressed as a plane wave. But the plane wave doesn't represent a physical solution because it's infinite in dimensions, implying infinite energy.
$$\vec E(\vec r,t)=\frac{A}{r}e^{-i(\vec k \vec r-\omega t)}$$
2 - Spherical waves are also solutions. The problem with these, is that they exhibit a singularity at the origin.
$$\vec E(\vec r,t)=\frac{A}{r}e^{-i(\vec k \vec r-\omega t)}$$.
Another solution are paraboloidal waves:
$$\vec E(\vec r,t)=\frac{A}{r}e^{-ikz}e^{-i(k \frac{x^2+y^2}{2z})-\omega t +\phi(z)}$$
The issue with the paraboloidal wave is that it is still not in a localized mode.(I have an idea as to what"localized mode" means, but I'd like for someone to give me  a proper definition if possible. The way I understand the problem here, is that, even though the paraboloidal wave is a solution of the paraxial Helmholtz equation, the expression of it contains no confinement in the transversal direction relative to the propagation one. I am not sure though).
So in the lecture what we do is, we introduce an enevelope function $\psi(x,,y,z)$. This is a function that slowly changes its amplitude in all the spatial dimensions. Then one can write for the paraboloidal solution:
$$\vec E(\vec r,t)=E_0\psi(x,y,z)e^{-i(kz-\omega t)}$$
From here one can derive the paraxial Helmholtz equation:
$$(\nabla_x^2 + \nabla_y^2-2ik\nabla_z)\psi=0$$
from which we get the final expression:
$$\vec E(\vec r, z)=E_0 \frac{w_0}{w(z)}e^{\frac{-r^2}{w^2(z)}-i\frac{kr^2}{2R(z)} -i[kz-\arctan(\frac z z_0)]}$$
where:
$w_0$ is beam waist.
$w(z)$ is beam radius.
$R(z)$ is wave front radius of curvature
$arctan \frac z z_0$ is the gouy phase.
Then we are introduced to the angular spectrum representation, a mathematical technique which describes optical fields in homogeneous media. What we do in this representation is that we expand a complex wave field into a summation of infinite number of plane waves of the same frequency and different directions.
Now this is the part I get confused. Initially we said that plane waves do not pose physical solutions, and we got the paraboloidal waves with an envelope function as the ones. But in the angular spectrum representation the complex wave field (which I believe is another expression for the waves of a field) can be represented as a superposition of plane waves. If that is the case then why the need for the paraboloidal wave when you can simply argue the superposition of plane waves? Also, does it make sense to consider the paraboloidal wave solution of the paraxial Helmholtz equation a superposition of plane waves in accordance to the representation ?

here I derived, or said more modestly, I recalled the Duffieux-Clemmow derivation of the paraxial and the parabolic wavefront approximation from the plane wave spectrum. I do not believe that there is a cleaner way of seeing all this, pun intended... Enjoy!

Plane wave expansions of optical fields in terms of angular spectra follow from the Helmholtz equation. It does not require the paraxial approximation. It leads to Fourier optics, which is a power way to analyze the propagation of optical field. (But "powerful" does not equate "easy".)
The solutions of the paraxial wave equation are usually in the form of polynomial Gaussian beams. While the Helmholtz equation provide the exact theory, the paraxial wave equation is only an approximation. One can expand the Gaussian beams in terms of plane wave expansions, which will behave like a Gaussian beam provided that the paraxial condition is well satisfied.
The reason why the paraxial approximation is used (when the paraxial condition is valid) is because Gaussian functions are easy to use. They make calculations simpler.
